# stm32 drawing current from 40 outputs at the same time

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, stm32, bjt, hardware

I have an hardware question about stm32 family.

I am designing a circuit with STM32F103VB. [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103vb.pdf) mentions that i can draw up to 25 mA current per pin(page 37 table 7). I need to drive 40 npn bjts with mcu. if I draw 15 mA current from 40 pin at the same time, what will happen? same table says that i can draw 150 mA total from power lines.

it is 40*15 = 600 mA total. it's more than half an amp. will it damage the mcu? how much current can i draw per pin for driving bjts at the same time?

Comment: The clue is in the power pin current limitation.

Comment: I would simply use N-channel MOSFETs in stead of BJTs.

Answer (score 0):

Page 37 has clear limits for max current.
You will have to reduce your current by /8 to drive 40 outputs.

Comment: That was going to be my answer!  Buffer the outputs with the appropriate 74xx series, or select super-beta transistors, or use Darlingtons, or use logic-level FETs.